# django: access dictionnary key inside of request session object

Tags: python, django

How is it possible to access a key from a dictionnary in a django view. I am banging my head off the wall with many errors and no solutions.

I access a dictionnary in a view as such:

```
def generate_pdf_assembly(request):
    data = request.session['sale']
    print(data)

    ...attempts...
    #total_ht = request.session['sale'].get('NetAmount')
    #total_ht = request.session['NetAmount']
    #total_ht = data.get('NetAmount')
    #print('total_ht', total_ht)


    my_company = MyCompany.objects.get(id = 1)
    context = {'data' : data, 'my_company' : my_company}
    print(context)
    
    return render(request, 'pdf/invoice_generator_assembly.html', context)
```

Important to mention that `data` output exactly what I need it to, which is:

```
[{'Id': '100121', 'Date': datetime.date(2020, 8, 10), 'Quantity': 1.0, 'NetAmount': 1.0, 'customer_name': <Customer_base: Customer_base object (unknown)>, 'id': None}]
```

I want to access the 'NetAmount' key. Please send some help! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly mistake. As you can see in the output:

```
[{'Id': '100121', 'Date': datetime.date(2020, 8, 10), 'Quantity': 1.0, 'NetAmount': 1.0, 'customer_name': <Customer_base: Customer_base object (unknown)>, 'id': None}]
```

Data is an array with 1 element. So access it like this:

```
data[0]['Id'] # prints out 100121
```

Comment: it does not work friend, trying data['NetAmount']  returns: ```list indices must be integers or slices, not str```

Comment: Try it as mentioned in the answer ```data[0]['NetAmount']```

Comment: The square brackets in the output indicate that this is a list with 1 dictionary in it

Comment: but if i understand properly, with using [0], I would only get the first value for that dictionnary key  right? I am trying to access all the values. in this small example, there is only one value for each key but there could be more you see

Comment: No, `data` is *not* a dictionary. It's a *list* containing 1 dictionary that's why [0] is necessary

Comment: ```print(type(data))``` will print out list, but ```print(type(data[0]))``` will print out dict, the one you want to access